# Problem with Checked listview in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am build an example with checked listview in Android. My problem is that I cant touch to the listview item to select it (as I did when I through out the checkbox).

please help me to resolve this.

Source code: [enter link description here](http://www.mediafire.com/?brzdu4brj533gt1)

Thanks.

Comment: don't use site like mediafire to share your code, use something like https://gist.github.com/ or direct paste it in the content of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the CheckBox as unfocusable. `android:focusable="false"`